# Convert Address data type into String

Tags: java

I have a 'Address' data type which contain `value = {"STATE":"AA","ZIP":"123456","COUNTRY":"USA","CITY":"CityA","STREET1":"Hollywood Street1"}`

How can i store it back into bellowing format?

```
Country~State~City~Street1~Street2~Street3~Zip~Latitude~Longitude~Time_zone
```

Recommend to use split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to decode the json string

```
({"STATE":"AA","ZIP":"123456","COUNTRY":"USA","CITY":"CityA","STREET1":"Hollywood Street1"})
```

take a lib from the bottom of [Json.org](http://www.json.org/)

after that u can decode it into an array

Comment: I tried to import a new jar name as json-simple-1.1.1.jar
and tried below 
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(fromAddress);

Answer (score 3):

It's JSON, use a JSON parser, like Jackson or GSON.

Comment: For information, [JavaEE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/doc/jsonp.htm) has an own JSON Parser now (JSR-353) ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can override toString() method for the class accessing this data type.

In the toString method you can iterate the data and using stringbuilder, create the desired string